# What is best suited to interface with authentication servers for a CLI tool?

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, saml, grpc

I am developing two linux programs, a CLI client and a server communicating via gRPC, and I now would like to authenticate users against a given private authorization server such as LDAP, Active Directory, etc.

I am confused regarding the various possible authentication flows. I think I can't use any classical flow including HTTP redirects since I shouldn't rely on a browser being installed or having internet access. I can't even define an endpoint I could redirect to (servers don't have internet access, and both are behind NATs).

So I was thinking of trying to store user's credentials as a JWT token file in the user's computer and then load it from my CLI client program to include it in my RPC requests and then validate it on the server-side. But, supposing I'm right, then what would be the best standard way of getting this token file?

Comment: does a user of the CLI have to enter their username/password and the server then authenticates those credentials with your LDAP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a browser you could use OAuth and the 'oob' (out of band) method where the CLI opens the browser and after the user authenticates it displays a number which the user copy/pastes into the CLI. This how my [flickr backup CLI](https://github.com/codebrane/flikbak) works. The number they copy/paste is because the CLI has no OAuth endpoint and the number is their access token to allow me to call the flickr api on their behalf.

If you can't use a browser the CLI can just accept a username/password from the user, send it to the server and receive a token in return. You don't really need anything fancy like JWT. A simple UUID would be enough. The UUID 'asserts' that the user is allowed to access the server's other RPC methods. The server would validate the UUID token to make sure it's still valid. If you need user information from the token, the server could do that. Keeps the user information off the client's disk and only the CLI can access that information, if the token is still valid.

So in effect, you need a new server RPC method, perhaps, `authenticate`, that accepts a username and password and returns a UUID token. All other RPC methods then need to accept that token and validate it before performing the requested function. As part of the server-side authentication process, the server could associate that token with the user information it got from the LDAP server so you don't need to store that information on the client. Lets you encrypt it on the server too and if the client needs it, it asks for it using the UUID token if it's still valid (time to live?). If it's no longer valid, the client just needs to ask for username/password again and the server can re-authenticate the user via LDAP and refresh the token and user information.

gRPC has [authentication protocols](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html) but the SSL/TLS doesn't seem to match your needs and the OAuth won't work as you don't have a browser. So perhaps rolling your own simple token service (`authenticate`) combined with LDAP authentication might be a workable option.

Comment: This sounds like how the Azure CLI works also, they have you login by loading a url and inputting a token the CLI provides you with.